# How to filter model results for multiple values for a many to many field in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following Model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    member = models.ManyToManyField(Player, through='GroupMember')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    join_password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1500)
    played = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    wins = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    losses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    experience = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

As you can see the group is made up of members who are players. What I would like to do is given two players I would like to be able to filter the groups that contain both of these players but I am unsure how to do this type of query.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If your `Player` model looks like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Then, you can execute this query:

```
Group.objects.filter(player__name__in=['Player1','Player2'])
```

Which roughly translates to *"find all groups that have players whose names match 'Player1' and 'Player2'"*

Or you can fetch the `player` objects individually:

```
p1 = Player.objects.get(name='Player1')
p2 = Player.objects.get(name='Player2')
groups = Group.objects.filter(player=p1).filter(player=p2)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually work, the first example runs an OR - that will show you all groups that contain BOTH players. The last example doesn't execute because you can't have two of the same kw arguments in the same method call. You could chain filters though, to get the desired effect: Group.objects.filter(player=p1).filter(player=p2)

Comment: I agree with @CharlesOffenbacher. It runs using OR.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. __in runs as an OR. While the documentation doesn't explicitly state that an OR is used, the SQL provided here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#in

Says that it's also using the IN SQL operator, which is an OR operation as defined here:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 32):

The easiest solution for you will be:

```
p1 = Player.objects.get(id=1)
p2 = Player.objects.get(id=2)
groups = Group.objects.filter(member=p1).filter(member=p2)
```

Note that you can't use the __in filter like this because this will result in an OR and return groups that don't contain both players:

```
Group.objects.filter(member__in=[1, 2])
```

Comment: Only this approach (multiple `.filter()` calls, one for each specific match) worked for me.  Using a complex `Q` lookup using or (`|`) did not match any objects because it built a SQL statement that required that the m2m field was _both_ match values, which is impossible.

Answer (score 13):

For me `__in` did not work. I ended up using the [complex Q lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)
which works perfectly and you can `or` filter conditions with. Use it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

p1 = Player.objects.get(name='Player1')
p2 = Player.objects.get(name='Player2')
querySet = Group.objects.filter(Q(member=p1) | Q(member=p2))
```

Comment: This makes it so easy

Comment: This will also return groups with only of the players in it. The question was about groups with specifically both players.

Comment: But what if the number of member to filter by is not known?

Comment: I'm not sure it answers the original comment, but in my case it works well. Not sure though on why it uses `|` instead of `or`

Comment: @Dr4kk0nnys `|` is a bitwise operator, used to compare binary numbers. Python's `or` is a boolean operator. In this case, `or` would just not work.