# Django filter filter with lists

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So, I have this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    colors = models.TextField(max_length=150,default = 'blue,green,blue')
```

and i want to filter it with a list of colors for example.
Any idea on how can i do it?
`colors = ["blue","green"]`
I need something like this.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(colors__icontains = colors)
```

Any kind of help or sugestion on how can i modify the model to filter will be apreciated .

Comment: As an aside you may wish to use the `choices` property to make a selection of possible colors (if you choose not to have a separate color model)

Comment: this will make me able to multi select colors ?

Comment: i think making a new model color and use the manytomanyfield will be the correct option.I'm still trying to get it working. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are storing colors as plain text and not using a related model, you cannot use the kind of filters you want.

The right way to do it is to use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/): a color can have multiple products and a product can have multiple colors:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Product(models.Model):
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color, related_name='colors')
```

Then, you can add colors like this:

```
blue = Color(name='blue')
blue.save()
red = Color(name='red')
red.save()
my_product = Product()
my_product.save()
my_product.colors.add(blue)
```

If you want to query all products that are red OR blue, just do:

```
Product.objects.filter(colors__in=[red, blue]) # Red and blue being Color instances
```

If you want all products that are red AND blue, just do as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16003998/2844093):

```
Product.objects.filter(colors=red).filter(colors=blue) # Red and blue being Color instances
```

Chaining filters like this is not especially convenient, so you'll probably want a custom [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) that will do it for you :

```
class AllManyToManyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def filter_all_many_to_many(self, attribute, *args):
        qs = self
        for arg in args:
            qs = qs.filter(**{attribute: arg})
        return qs

class Product(models.Model):
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color, related_name='colors')
    objects = AllManyToManyQuerySet.as_manager()
```

And use it like this:

```
Product.objects.all().filter_all_many_to_many('colors', red, blue) # red and blue being color instances
```

Another filter method is:

```
product_list = Product.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, [Q(colors__name=c) for c in colors]))
```

It's untested, but it should probably work, and you can use the queryset on other classes if you need it elsewhere, keeping you code clean and DRY ;)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the unpacking on the QuerySet class !

Answer (score 4):

You could just iterate over it, nothing gets executed till you require the data

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for color in colors:
    products = products.filter(colors__icontains=color)
```

Comment: any idea if is possible to make it on a single line? :)

Comment: @RusMine - Its possible that using `colors__in=colors` might work but I haven't tested it (think its the wrong way round), failing that, did you try with `icontains`?

Comment: @RusMine - Didn't think so, but for what its worth, I think its pretty clear what these 3 lines are doing, there probably is a way to construct a set of filters in one line but that would be a lot more confusing that what is here which is why I dont want to show that way

Comment: is a very good answer for my question ,i upvoted it , but i wont accept it as a final answer because i'm waiting for a single line filter. I will later need to filter for gender, category .. etc and i want to make it on a single line :)

Comment: @RusMine - Sure no worries, it *should* be possible but it would be very ugly and you don't gain anything. What I referring to by "nothing gets executed" is that django querysets are done lazily so the database isn't actually queried until you need data

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I didn't get which of the logical operations: `AND` or `OR` you need. But it's not a big deal. Here's a one-liner:

```
from operator import or_, and_  # i'm not quite sure which one you actually need.
from django.db.models import Q

colors = ["blue","green"]
Product.objects.filter(reduce(or_, [Q(colors__icontains=c) for c in colors]))
```

But speaking of the desing, I can't say there's any reason to store these values like that. Please, consider the [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield), if you don't want to use `ManyToMany` for some reason.