# query the database using django object Q to the same field with the operator &

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I apologize in advance if my question has already been there, but I have not found.

there is a model:

```
    class Artikul_cabinets(models.Model):
         artikul_cabinets = models.CharField(verbose_name="Артикул шкафа", max_length=20)
         title_cabinets = models.CharField(verbose_name="Описание шкафа", max_length=200)
         width_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Width_cabinets)
         depth_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Depth_cabinets)
         unit_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Unit_cabinets)
         weight_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Weight_cabinets)
         type_cabinets = models.ForeignKey(Type_cabinets, default=1)
         color_cabinets = models.ForeignKey(Color_cabinets)
         glass_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Glass_cabinets)

    class Meta:
         verbose_name_plural = "Артикул шкафа"

    def __str__(self):
         return self.artikul_cabinets
```

It is necessary to make the selection on the field

```
    glass_cabinets = models.ManyToManyField(Glass_cabinets)
```

The selection is done as follows

```
    data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=perf) & 
                       Q(glass_cabinets=glass)
```

`perf` and `glass` the variables with different values.
And I returned to my empty QuerySet, although the database element with the parameters 'perf' and 'glass' are present in the record.

Tell me what I'm doing wrong.

also tried:

```
    data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=perf),
                       Q(glass_cabinets=glass)
```

and also did not work, though if you put the operator '|' the conditions or work out correctly.

Comment: so if you used `|` works correctly?

Comment: yes. works correctly

Comment: `data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=perf),                  Q(glass_cabinets=glass)` this returns the objects that has both `perf` and `glass`. Do you have any object that has both?

Comment: returns an empty self-interest as well as `data = Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(Q(glass_cabinets=perf) & Q(glass_cabinets=glass)`

Comment: Do you have any object that has both together?

Comment: of course - http://clip2net.com/s/3uqrPGX

Comment: `|` should not work OK then correctly with other values. It will return the objects that have only one of them. Try Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(glass_cabinets=perf).filter(glass_cabinets=glass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you should do `Artikul_cabinets.objects.filter(glass_cabinets=perf).filter(glass_cabinets=glass‌​)`

check [How to filter model results for multiple values for a many to many field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410647/how-to-filter-model-results-for-multiple-values-for-a-many-to-many-field-in-djan)