# Django-ORM: Check whether multiple items are in DB while minimizing calls

Tags: django, django-orm

Assume that from an external API call, we get the following response:

```
resp = ['123', '67283', '99829', '786232']
```

These are `external_id` fields for our objects, defined in our `Article` model. Some of which may already exist in database, while others don't.

Before returning a response, we need to check whether each `external_id` corresponds to a record in our database, and if not, we need to create it and fetch additional info from another, third, source.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Right now I can't think of something better than:

```
for external_id in resp:
    if not Article.objects.filter(external_id=external_id).exists():
        # item doesn't exist, go fetch more data and create object
    else:
        # already exists, do something else
```

But there must be a better way..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter model results for multiple values for a many to many field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410647/how-to-filter-model-results-for-multiple-values-for-a-many-to-many-field-in-djan)

Comment: @solarissmoke - can you please explain how is this a duplicate if it doesn't deal with many-to-many-field? maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The same logic (using `__in`) will work for a many to many field. Have you tried it?

Comment: @solarissmoke tried *what*? I'm not looking to find a different an object from a different model, I'm looking to figure out whether I have in my database an item with an `external_id` that matches the `external_ids` that I'm getting from a 3rd party service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) for this task. Following code will issue only one database call:

```
expected_ids = set(int(pk) for pk in resp)
exist_ids  = set(Article.objects.filter(external_id__in=resp)
                                .values_list('external_id', flat=True))
not_exist_ids = list(expected_ids - exist_ids)
```